# News & Weather Widget Not Updating

Tags: sync, app-widgets, news-and-weather

I have a news & weather widget on my Nexus S home screen, set to show the weather for my current location. In its settings, I have it set to update once an hour along with automatic location tracking. Neither of these things work anymore since about a month ago (possibly the 2.3.4 update?). I have background data enabled, sync enabled, and I don't have any battery saver style programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself after trying a few things. I deleted the News & Weather app's data by going to Settings>Applications>Manage Applications>All, Tapping "News & Weather", and then "Clear Data". I needed to delete and re-add the widget and set my refresh settings again, but now it works.

Comment: worked for me too

Comment: Did not work for me...

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is free up your internal memory. Many apps stop working if your internal memory is near full or has reached a certain storage limit. Move vidoes and apps go your sd card and it will start working fine