# How can I get the location to update again in my News and Weather widget?

Tags: geolocation, news-and-weather

On my Galaxy Nexus running stock Jellybean 4.1.1 the News & Weather widget thinks I'm in Hong Kong airport, and has for the last week.

[image: News & Weather widget showing wrong location]

I have been to Hong Kong airport 3 times in the last month (it's a hub airport for Australasia) but never stayed there for longer than 3 hours. I'm currently in London, and have been either here or elsewhere in England for the last 7 days.

If I tap the widget and tap the refresh icon (circled-arrows) it does show the correct location until the next auto-refresh interval (I have it set for 6 hours) when it will switch back to "Chek Lap Kok Airport" in Hong Kong again.

Following the instructions in this previous question [News & Weather Widget Not Updating](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/) I have deleted the widget from my home screen, done a Clear Data and Clear Cache on the News & Weather app in the applications listing, and then re-added to my home screen. This sorted it out initially, and then 6 hours later it switched back to Hong Kong again.

I have all of the Location Services in the Android settings enabled, Google Maps shows me in the correct location whether I'm outdoors (on GPS) or indoors (using network location). I leave Wifi switched on for most of the day, and this happens during the day at work when I'm using mobile data, and overnight at home when I'm connected to my wifi.

Comment: Bizarrely nothing worked to fix this while in the UK, but ever since I got off a plane in Chicago 2 days ago, the location's been working with no problems in the US, so far. Will try to work out what's fixed it and see if it breaks again in any of my next few countries (or when I go home again).

Answer (score 4):

- Tap the widget so it opens the **News & Weather** app.
- Tap the overflow menu and go into `Settings`.
- Tap `Weather settings`
- Check or uncheck "Use my location" as necessary. Clear out the value under "Set location" as necessary

Comment: Thanks, I did have "Use My Location" ticked, and whether that's ticked or not, there's nothing set in "Set Location", tapping that just comes up with a blank "Type a town/city or postcode" box. Will try leaving "Use My Location unticked for a few hours, then switch it back again to see if it kicks anything back to life.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'm thinking that Google hasn't been paying much attention to their stock Android apps except for the big hitters. There are some other Weather widget apps out there you might try instead. I like 1Weather.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm starting to think you're right and I'll have to look around at other widgets. Annoying when I've been to various parts of the UK and at least 6 different countries with the location working fine for the most of the last year until I got home last week!

Comment: Beautiful Widgets are also another good alternative